# "Enjoyment of" or "enjoyment by"?

Tags: meaning

A job description I am re-writing contains the words "facilitate the enjoyment of all visitors to the gallery."

To me this says that the visitors are being enjoyed, not the gallery.

Should it actually say "facilitate enjoyment of the gallery by visitors" or alternatively, "facilitate visitors' enjoyment of the gallery"?

Comment: I agree with you that the alternatives are better. I'm undecided about whether the original is wrong, or just gratuitously awkward.

Comment: I agree with your skepticism about the first version. "Facilitate visitors' enjoyment of the gallery" sounds best to my ears, and is unambiguous.

Comment: '... the enjoyment of' may be followed by either the thing to be enjoyed ('for the enjoyment of music': 760 000 Google hits; art: 325 000;; 'the enjoyment of privileges': 83 000) OR the group doing or intended to do the enjoying ('for the enjoyment of the audience': 22 000 000 Google hits; 'for the enjoyment of the public': 8 000 000 Google hits). There _is_ the possibility of ambiguity, but it will rarely arise.

Comment: Depending on how much freedom you have with the wording, you might drop the stiffly institutional "facilitate" in favor of something a bit more natural, such "help ensure that visitors to the gallery enjoy their stay" or "help make every visitor's time spent at the gallery more enjoyable."

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of things we say and write everyday can have more than one interpretation. We rely more on listener's attention and recognition of context than perhaps we realise.

*He walked down the street and turned into a shop*, will 99.9999999% of the time mean just that. But in a book entitle *The Wizard of Cleethorpes* it may perhaps mean something else.

Everyone knows what *facilitate the enjoyment of all visitors to the galleries* means - especially in an age when the verb *enjoy* is being increasingly used as an intransitive verb - *enjoy!*

But clearly it has the capacity to be ambiguous, and would sound especially sinister if you extended the description to the job of a zoo keeper:

*Shall facilitate the enjoyment of visitors to the lions and tigers.*

Best version, in my view is:

*Shall facilitate the visitors' enjoyment of the galleries*

'Facilitate' is the kind of word which appears in job specifications, curricula vitae, etc. It sounds awkward and a wee bit pompous, but it is difficult to replace.

This post has been considerably modified from the original version, after taking on board the comment of @Edwin Ashworth - below.

Comment: Sorry. It's not clearly wrong to me. Any more than 'Flying planes can be dangerous' is. It sounds ridiculous though, and I'd use "... make it possible for all visitors to the gallery to really enjoy ..." The fact that a sentence may justifiably be taken to have more than one meaning does not make it 'wrong', though a rewrite to disambiguate would be sensible. Is 'He just left the table' wrong?

Comment: You mean 'ate the sausages but left the table'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes I was 'wrong' to say 'wrong'. It is not 'wrong' just ambiguous and it needs revision for that reason.

Answer (score -1):

How about keeping it to plain English:

> ... help the visitors to enjoy the gallery...